# How do you quantify the handicap in this game?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I was playing tennis with my brother. We were playing in a format such that in order to win you have to score $X$ number of points. I gave my brother a handicap.

Scenario 1:
We play until $7$ points. He gets a $5-0$ lead.

Scenario 2:
We play until $10$ points. He gets a $7-0$ lead.

In the first scenario, I only get two chances to err. In the second scenario, I have a buffer of 3 points. However, in the first scenario, I have to win less points to catch up. Whereas in the second scenario I have to win more points to catch up. How do I quantify the tradeoff between the margin of error and the raw number of points needed to win?

Comment: It depends on how good you think you are compared to your brother! A simple model is to assume that you have a probability of $p$ of winning the next point (so $1 - p$ that he wins it instead) and that different points are independent, then you can numerically simulate your probability of winning in each case and maybe even write down a closed form to see how it depends on $p$. Whether that's a realistic model, who knows.

Comment: Following the previous comment: if you have probability $p$ of winning each point, then I think a handicap of $\frac{X(2p-1)}{p}$ points leads to you each having equal chances of winning the match